# Multi-screen background image sizes

Tags: background-image, tablet, retina-display, smartphone, multiple-monitors

I'm working on an image heavy web site that's essentially got three designs for multiple screens: smart phone, tablet and desktop.

The main feature of this site is background/fullscreen images. Has anyone got any recommendations regarding the suggested sizes that these background images should be?

They'll all be progressive jpegs as that seems the [most sensible path for resizing and optimisation](http://calendar.perfplanet.com/2012/progressive-jpegs-a-new-best-practice/).

Handling the different images sizes will be another test, but essentially it seems sensible to handle it on the client side since this design allows for a polite loader.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend formatting for a non-retina phone such as the iPhone 3Gs at **480x320**, a retina iPhone 5 at **1136x640**, a retina iPad at **2048x1536**, a retina mac book pro at **2880x1800**. Then setup your media queries to pick the best of those sizes for non-retina ipad, standard desktop (your default image), and the Google Nexus 10 which has a display near the MBP retina (2560x1600).

For background images you will want to use media queries. For fullscreen images what I've done is implement a JavaScript module that allows you to imitate the [picture element](http://responsiveimages.org/) proposed by the Responsive Images Community Group. Or if you prefer you could go the "srcset" route.